# DataTable Compute object to decimal

Tags: c#, type-conversion, c#-2.0

I'm trying to get a decimal value, by using the `Compute` function with a `DataTable`. I need the maximum value of the `verNumber` column, which will *always* be a whole number (`1`,`2`,`3`) or a decimal with one place (`1.1`,`1.2`,`2.3`,`3.1`, etc) but can also end up like `1.1.1` or `4.1.2`. It will never be anything like `1.0` or `2.11`. Think document version numbers.

No calculations need to be done with these numbers, they are just passed to a function which currently accepts a string (but could be changed easily), so a string containing the maximum value should work, although as proof of concept I'm trying to get it working with numbers like `2` and `2.1`. The data type of the database table this comes from (`GetVersionsTable() method`) is `int`, if that matters.

If I try to use this code with a decimal it complains that it's an invalid cast. Using `int` works, but obviously removes the decimal place if it's present.

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = doc.GetVersionsTable(true) as System.Data.DataTable;
decimal maxVal = (decimal) dt.Compute( "MAX(verNumber)", string.Empty );
```

Results in `specified cast not valid`

I have also tried using `decimal.Parse` which has similar complaints.

I tried just getting a string directly;

```
string maxVal = (string) dt.Compute( "MAX(verNumber)", string.Empty );
```

This gave me `Unable to cast object type of System.Int32 to type System.String`, which suggests that it's an `int`, but why can't I cast it to a decimal?

Note that while I would love to use Linq to solve this, I can't, as I'm stuck with no linq support.

Comment: If the verNumber column type is int, then it just can't hold 1.1 (not an int) let alone 1.2.3 which isn't any sort of number.

Comment: My bad, there is a label column too which contains the `1.1.2` type numbers. I'll see if I can return that instead as it's a string, then I can just use it, with the code above to get the max verNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose verNumber is string (1.1.1 is neither int or decimal) Please post some minimal reproduction code. I've tried code bellow - and it is working correctly.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear(); 
dt.Columns.Add("verNumber");
object[] o = { "1.2.1" };
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1.1.1" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1.4" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "4.1.4" });
string maxVal = (string)dt.Compute( "MAX(verNumber)", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(maxVal);
```